# Pandas groupby agg/apply with different functions for different rows in group

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to perform a groupby aggregation.  My dummy Dataframe looks like this:

```
print (df)
    ID  Industry  Value 1  Value 2
0    1   Finance     0.25       99
1    1   Finance     0.50       73
2    1   Finance     0.25       53
3    1  Teaching     0.75       80
4    1  Teaching     0.25       78
5    1  Teaching     0.50       99
6    2   Finance     0.50       75
7    2   Finance     0.25       56
8    2   Finance     0.25       80
9    2  Teaching     0.50       79
10   3   Finance     0.25       61
11   3   Finance     0.75       87
12   3   Finance     0.75       97
13   3   Finance     0.25       99
14   3   Finance     0.25       76
15   3  Teaching     0.25       73
16   3  Teaching     0.75       68
17   3  Teaching     0.25       59
18   3  Teaching     0.25       60
```

I want to group by ID and Industry and I want to create a new field called say "Expected".  Expected will be equal to:

- If it's the first row of the group, Value 1 + Value 2
- If it's any other row in the group Expected value of the row above in that group *minus* (Value 1 * Value 2) for the current row, so that Expected value looks as follows:

[image]

I'd like to avoid a loop if possible.  Any help would appreciated as multiple attempts using iloc, groupby agg, groupby transform have come up short for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First set new column by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and then use [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
m = df.duplicated(['ID','Industry'])
df['new'] = np.where(m, -df['Value 1'] * df['Value 2'], df['Value 1'] + df['Value 2'])
df['new'] = df.groupby(['ID','Industry'])['new'].cumsum()
print (df)
    ID  Industry  Value 1  Value 2     new
0    1   Finance     0.25       99   99.25
1    1   Finance     0.50       73   62.75
2    1   Finance     0.25       53   49.50
3    1  Teaching     0.75       80   80.75
4    1  Teaching     0.25       78   61.25
5    1  Teaching     0.50       99   11.75
6    2   Finance     0.50       75   75.50
7    2   Finance     0.25       56   61.50
8    2   Finance     0.25       80   41.50
9    2  Teaching     0.50       79   79.50
10   3   Finance     0.25       61   61.25
11   3   Finance     0.75       87   -4.00
12   3   Finance     0.75       97  -76.75
13   3   Finance     0.25       99 -101.50
14   3   Finance     0.25       76 -120.50
15   3  Teaching     0.25       73   73.25
16   3  Teaching     0.75       68   22.25
17   3  Teaching     0.25       59    7.50
18   3  Teaching     0.25       60   -7.50
```